# Trying to insert a front/back to my stack

Tags: python, stack

I am trying to insert "FRONT: " AND " :BACK"  to the end of my string (self._data) but my results keep printing as:

'FRONT: [10, 8, 7, 5] [10, 8, 7, 5] [10, 8, 7, 5] [10, 8, 7, 5] :BACK'

When i want them to print as 'FRONT: 10, 8, 7, 5 :BACK'

Self._data is empty and i have pushed/popped numbers to end with a string of 10, 8, 7, 5.

```
 def __str__(self):
    result = "FRONT:"
    for x in self._data: 
         result = result + " " + str(self._data)
    result = result + " :BACK"
    return result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You are adding `self._data` instead, you should add `x`.
- This will fix it.

```py
def __str__(self):
    result = "FRONT:"
    for x in self._data: 
         result = result + " " + str(x)
    result = result + " :BACK"
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

in the code you do `result = result + " " + str(self._data)`

where you should do `result = result + " " + str(x)`